# removing duplicate rows pandas with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Data

```
ID  Field1  Field2
1    A        '1'
2    A        ' '
3    B        '2'
4    B        '3'
```

Want

```
ID  Field1  Field2
1    A        '1'
4    B        '3'
```

I have multiple duplicate rows which only differ on Field2 (character field).
For each distinct Field1 I want to only keep the row which has the *max* character value for Field2 (i.e. '3'>'2'>'1'>'(blank space)')

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['Field1', 'Field2']).drop_duplicates('Field1', keep='last')

   ID Field1 Field2
0   1      A    '1'
3   4      B    '3'
```

---

### `groupby` and `apply`

I don't recommend this solution.  I just wanted to show it.

```
df.groupby('Field1', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.iloc[d['Field2'].values.astype(str).argmax()])

   ID Field1 Field2
0   1      A    '1'
1   4      B    '3'
```

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly.. slight update though. If I had another field 'Field3' which needed to be sorted descending (so the last value would be the min). Is it possible to add that to the same query?(i.e. select the row with max Field2 and min Field3)

Comment: I'm sure it is possible but I'm confused as to what you want.  Best advice is to roll that into another question.

Comment: Thanks, added a new one

Answer (score 0):

Try the grouping function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Field2': ['1', ' ', '2', '3']})

df.groupby(['Field1']).max()
```